# Migrating serialized/json java class to new version

Tags: java, json, serialization

I was wondering if anyone knows of a technique or library to easily update a serialized/json'd java class to a new version. Say, for example, that i have a bunch of serialized classes, and i decide to remove a field in a new version. The operation will fail when i try to deserialize the bytes into this new java class.

I there a library or technique to handle migrating the data somewhere?